# SF novel featuring a ship called Kraftwerk II

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, transhuman

There's a novel I read years ago but I can't remember the title. Here's what I do recall, hope it rings a bell with someone....

1. It begins with the 2 main characters in ship called Kraftwerk II - they are chased into an asteroid field/meteor storm or some such by another larger vessel, but it turns out their pursuers were just using them for combat practice and did not really mean to destroy them.
2. One of the characters has been 'modified' - which means they are able to temporarily change themselves and speed up their reflexes. They grow fangs and claws as well.

Unfortunately that's about all I've got.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Was it "Space Mavericks" or its sequel, "Children of the Night"? Does that ring a bell?  [Amazon link for Space Mavericks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0843921005) and [this I found on a forum.](http://www.sffchronicles.co.uk/forum/529547-spaceship-called-kraftwerk-a-guy-finds-a-ring.html) The author is Michael Kring.

Comment: Wow that was fast - thanks!

It certainly sounds like it from the forum entry - I'll do some more digging to confirm.

Comment: Yep - this is definitely it. Many thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I cheated. I just googled "Kraftwerk" and "spaceship". Disturbingly enough, it worked. Kraftwerk 2 just gives German techno music.